# How do i solve an equation using loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

if *x* and *y* are positive integers, *x+xy+y=54*. Solve *x+y*

I want to "translate" this equation into R language, but i'm farily new.
I've tried using while loops but i don't know if it is the best approach for this problem

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that you've tried? Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to find positive integer solutions for the equation x + xy + y = 54 and then calculate the sum of x and y.

```
for (x in 1:53) {
  for (y in 1:53) {
    if (x + x * y + y == 54) {
      sum_x_y = x + y
      cat("Solution found: x =", x, "and y =", y, ", x + y =", sum_x_y, "\n")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the R approach vectorizing the method.

```
#define all possible x values
x<- 1:54

#solve
y <- (54-x)/(1+x)

#find the values where y is an integer
x[which((y-as.integer(y)) ==0)]
```

An additional shortcut is to realize that y  must be >=2, so one only needs to solve for x between 1 and 26.